# Can we Use exchange server with public ip address in one domain for smtp server in other domain in sharepoint Farm ? How?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can we Use exchange server with public ip address in one domain  for smtp server in other domain  in sharepoint Farm ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make sure the public IP address is reachable from SharePoint.

Once this is validated, you can configure the server details using Central Admin

1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the Farm Administrators group on the server that is running the SharePoint Central Administration website.
2. In Central Administration, click System Settings.
3. On the System Settings page, in the E-Mail and Text Messages (SMS) section, click  Configure outgoing e-mail settings.
4. On the Outgoing E-Mail Settings page, in the Mail Settings section, type the SMTP server name for outgoing email (for example, mail.example.com) in the Outbound SMTP server box.
5. In the From address box, type the email address as you want it to be displayed to email recipients.
6. In the Reply-to address box, type the email address to which you want email recipients to reply.
7. In the Character set list, select the character set that is appropriate for your language.
8. Click OK.